# Changing f-string code editor color in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Pretty much everything appearance-wise is customizable in the QGIS Python editor, but f-strings don't seem to be included.
F-strings are a very dark purple color in which can be hard to see.

Showcase:

[image: example]

It may not be very obvious here but it is an issue when you are zoomed out further.

Anyway, nothing among the regular color fields in the settings seem to handle this type of code and I can't find where the default color is set. I tried using a color picker on this which gave me #7a0478, but that value doesn't show up anywhere in QGIS3.ini.
I'm using QGIS 3.22.7 for reference.

Where would I need to change this or is it not supported in this version?